# How to get a horizontally fixedSize LazyVStack to consider width of it longest child, rather than it's first child?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to get `LazyVStack.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)` to set its size based on the width of its longest child, as VStack does, rather than its first child? I would happily use another lazy container that I can place in a ScrollView, however I have the same problem with LazyVGrid. Thank you

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var values = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text("\(value)")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
            
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(values, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text("\(value)")
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .background(.blue)
                }
            }
            .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of vstacks]

Comment: A `LazyVStack` doesn't know what its longest child is. It's lazy by definition. "Is this the longest child?" "Oh I don't know, there might be views later down the line that is longer. I haven't displayed them all yet".

Comment: Yes, that's right, but why doesnt the LazyVStack know the length of its current longest child?

Comment: It technically does, but if it resizes according to the current longest child, it might cause other views to appear, and "the current longest child" changes as a result. Implementing that correctly would be rather complicated, and there might not even be an "equilibrium point".